# I return from 'detached HEAD' state and git deleted my .env file from the local directory

Tags: reactjs, git, environment-variables, command-line-interface, git-detached-head

I was checking my commit history to fixing a bug.
I use
`git checkout 4a3cf4ebfc8c3d4a7f8b055b3f38cc90acf2a0cd` to Switching between commits.
I was in - `'detached HEAD' state`.

in that state, I use some command like:
`git add .`
`git commit -m "massage"`
Then I Switch different commits by `git checkout e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`.

I return from 'detached HEAD' state by using the command: `git checkout master`.

Now, my `.env` file is gone from the local directory.

I am creating a react app. I am using `.gitignore` file to ignore my API key in `.env` file.

Comment: It is almost always a mistake to run "git commit" in "detached head" state. At least not unless you immediately associate the new commit with a branch by running "git branch $branch_name".

Answer (score 3):

Given some particular conditions (which must be the case here), this is normal.

We start with these facts:

- Git stores *commits*.  Git does not store files, nor branches, but rather entire commits.  (Each commit does store files, but you work with an entire commit at a time.  Branch names help you—and Git—*find* commits, because the commit numbers are so random-looking.)
- Each commit has a unique number, which looks random, but isn't: it's the commit's hash ID.  The hash ID is actually a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit.  No part of any commit can ever be changed.
- Each commit actually stores two things: a snapshot—a complete set of *all* of your files—and some metadata.  The entire commit is completely read-only, and all the files *in* the commit are stored in a read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated form.
- This in turn means that you cannot actually work with the files inside a commit.  The files that you see and work with are *copied out of* some commit, into an area Git calls your *working tree* or *work-tree*.
- Hence the `git checkout` command, when given a name like `master` or a raw commit hash like `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`, has to *copy the files that are stored (forever) in that commit* (but are not usable by programs like ReactJS) into your work-tree (where they are *are* usable by programs like ReactJS).

This means that the files you see and work with, in your work-tree, are not actually *in* Git in the first place.  They're just copies of files from some *commit* in Git.

Now, suppose that the last commit of your `master` branch is `a123456...`.  I made up hash ID, but we can be pretty sure that whatever the actual hash ID is, it's *not* `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`.  So your Git has, inside it, as two *different commits*:

- `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`: this commit *has a `.env` file in it*.
- `a123456...`: this commit *does not have a `.env` file in it*.

When you check out commit `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`, Git must extract the saved `.env` file to your work-tree.

When you switch back to `a123456...`, Git must *remove* that saved `.env` file to get it out of the way.

> I am using .gitignore file to ignore my API key in .env file.

Unfortunately, the `.gitignore` file does not actually tell Git to ignore files.  It can't: commit `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463` *has* the `.env` file in it, and no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.

So, when you extract commit `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`, Git copies the `.env` file out of that commit (into both Git's *index* or *staging area*, and your work-tree).  If your `.env` file has valuable data in it, this copying-out process could destroy the valuable data.

Usually, when `git checkout` might destroy the contents of a file, Git will warn you about this, and refuse to do the `git checkout` until you have saved those file contents elsewhere.  Unfortunately, one of the side effects of listing a file in `.gitignore` is that it sometimes (not always, but sometimes) gives Git permission to destroy the file's contents.

Perhaps, though, the `.env` file contents you had that *were* in your work-tree, but not in commit `a123456...`, matched the contents in commit `e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463`.  **If that was the case**, `git checkout e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463` left the contents in place, without actually destroying anything.  Unfortunately Git will still *remove* the file when switching back, but you can, at this point, instruct Git to retrieve the contents of that one particular file from that one particular commit:

```
git show e255fb94e967c4c1463c25e44090bfc5a40b8463:.env > .env
```

for instance.

Comment: Oh, man. You are right. I try your commend. It gives me, an empty .env File. Thanks for your help anyway. I restore the API key.